# what is the LB algorithm in WSO2 ELB and how to configure it

Tags: algorithm, wso2, cluster-computing

In "http://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB203/ELB+Architecture", it mentioned that a Synapse endpoint by the name "ServiceDynamicLoadBalanceEndpoint" routes messages to the appropriate node. I want to what is the exact algorithm supported by the ELB to route messages to the appropriate node, random? round-robin? or others?

And how to configure it.

If someone know about it, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the default endpoint used by WSO2 ELB is TenantAwareLoadBalanceEndpoint and it uses Round Robin algorithm by default. But unfortunately, with this endpoint it is not configurable at the moment.

But we've recently made the endpoint used by WSO2 ELB configurable. Please refer to https://wso2.org/jira/browse/LB-68

This will probably available on next ELB release (2.1.0) which will happen within next few weeks. With a custom endpoint, you can change the load balancing algorithm.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is helpful for me.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Currently WSO2 ELB use round robin algorithm in default. If anyone needs a different algorithm he can implement a algorithm and plug in to WSO2 ELB as a custom jar from next release.